# Android studio / IntelliJ build window automatically show

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am trying to have my Android Studio build window, popup whenever I build.

Is this possible?

I don't want to window in floating mode, as I would like to be able to hide it using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

I have tried every variation of pinned and docked, but when it is hidden, it seems to always stay hidden....

Comment: Do you mean that after running "Build | Build Project" IDE doesn't open "Build" tool window with errors? Do you have  "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle" option enabled in "File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner"?

Comment: I would like the build window to open when the build commences.

Comment: @ScottF is it possible to provide a screenshot, also did you click on background when the build was happeneing?

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this by recording a macro. [Here I recorded a video of the whole process.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s4qk2yn0kjz99ge/Macro%20in%20Android%20Studio.mp4?dl=0)

Alternatively, if you prefer a written method, you can follow the steps below;

1. Go to **Edit** menu > **Macros**.
2. Click on **Start Macro Recording**.

Now your actions in Android Studio will be recorded.

3. Click **View** menu > **Tool Windows** >> **Build**.
4. Now build your app.
5. Stop macro recording (a tiny status bar at the bottom right corner of Android Studio, visible only when macro recording is in progress)
6. Give your macro a name, e.g. Build and Show Status.

Now go to **Edit** menu > **Macros** and click on your macro name to run it. It will start the build process and show Build window. To make it more quick, assign a keyboard short to your macro;

1. Click on **File** menu > **Settings** (or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)
2. On **Settings** dialog box, choose **Keymap**.
3. In right pane of **Keymap**, choose **Main Menu** > **Edit**.
4. Expand **Macros**, and right-click on your macro name.
5. Click on **Add Keyboard Shortcut**.
6. Assign it an unused shortcut as per your convenience (I used <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>)
7. Click **Ok**, and then **Ok** on **Settings** dialog box.

Hope my answer helps you. I tried this in **Android Studio 3.2.1**.

Answer (score 2):

I never seen that build open automatically. You can **use a shortcut** to open build toolbar.

- There is no default shortcut to open build toolbar, so you can create your own. Whenever you build. then hit your shortcut too. That's what I guess.

[image]